# GLM binomial with one category containing zero patients

Tags: generalized-linear-model, p-value

I have a data set where I performed a GLM in order to see what effect certain radiological parameters had on the end result.

```
Call:
glm(formula = result ~ age_over_under_60 + Sex + 
    radiological_parameter_1 + radiological_parameter_2 + radiological_parameter_3 + 
    radiological_parameter_4 + radiological_parameter_4, family = "binomial", 
    data = my_data)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.11049  -0.45486  -0.38344   0.00015   2.39896  

Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     -2.81958    0.61284  -4.601 4.21e-06 ***
age_over_under_60                0.52001    0.55278   0.941  0.34686    
Sex                              0.08305    0.66897   0.124  0.90120    
radiological_parameter_1         2.83452    0.67390   4.206 2.60e-05 ***
radiological_parameter_2         1.16334    1.13437   1.026  0.30511    
radiological_parameter_3        -0.27375    0.58737  -0.466  0.64117    
radiological_parameter_4        17.38227 1215.31571   0.014  0.98859    
radiological_parameter_5         1.85178    0.62290   2.973  0.00295 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 162.43  on 137  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 101.48  on 130  degrees of freedom
  (7 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 117.48

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 16
```

The data for parameter 4 is striking me as weird as 8 out of 8 patients who fulfilled this parameter had bad end results meanwhile 30/130 who did not fulfil it had bad results.

Can anyone help and explain the high p-value and possibly what I could do differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the p value.  Anything else strike you as weird?  The standard error and log odds ratio are enormous.

I take it that the variable is binary. If so I feel confident saying you are suffering from *quasi/complete separation*.  You'd be best to search this site for that term to find ways to combat this.